# What is the difference between a cavity resonator and a faraday cage?

Tags: microwave, faraday-cage, resonator

In my internet research, I found that several people believed **microwave ovens** act as faraday cages and some said they act as cavity resonators.

I know that Faraday cages block incoming electric fields in microwaves/EMwaves, while in a cavity resonator, microwaves/electromagnetic waves cannot penetrate through it.

Faraday cage blocks electric fields by generating another electric field inside it. While Cavity works on the principle of standing waves. It traps electric fields by making standing waves.

But How can we explain microwave ovens? Can we say that it works both the principle? Can we say the microwave oven is Inverse Faraday cage as well as cavity resonator?

Comment: Look up magnetron.

Comment: The difference is the difference between *inside* and *outside*. Also, Cavity resonator is shaped and sized for a specific frequency. Faraday cage need not be.

Comment: Also, a cavity resonator needs only two opposing surfaces to get back and forth reflection. I think a Faraday cage needs to be closed on all sides.

Comment: "*block*", "*cannot penetrate through*". Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: Things which can't penetrate through bounce off. When things of the right frequency bounce off the right sized spacing between the walls, they resonate.

Comment: There are two important components in a microwave : a cavity resonator, which resonates, and a Faraday cage, which stops EM waves escaping. (OK and a bunch of other stuff to support these)